I'm trying to run the following code but i keep coming with an error in the last line
This is the code I am running:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier   
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
    from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score,auc
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve,roc_auc_score, plot_roc_curve

This was the error:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call      last)
<ipython-input-3-d1b430d75826> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
      6 from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
----> 7 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score,  recall_score, roc_curve, roc_auc_score, plot_roc_curve
      8 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
      9 from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_roc_curve' from 'sklearn.metrics' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py)

Please let me know if my code is wrong or it is missing anything?

You have an outdated version?

The error is occurring because plot_roc_curve has been deprecated in scikit-learn version 1.0 and removed in version 1.2. You can instead use RocCurveDisplay from the sklearn.metrics module since Google Colab seems to be using 1.3.2 right now:
# import sklearn
# print(sklearn.__version__)  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, roc_curve, roc_auc_score, RocCurveDisplay

And for plotting the ROC curve, you can use RocCurveDisplay like this:
RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(your_model, your_X_test, your_y_test)
plt.show()


The ImportError you've encountered means that the plot_roc_curve and its not available in the version of scikit-learn that you're using. The plot_roc_curve function was added to scikit-learn in version 0.22 and if you'r using an older version you may need to update scikit-learn so you'r options are you need to either update scikit-learn or use alternative methods to plot the ROC curve.
To fix the issue, you can update scikit-learn by just pasting this into you'r terminal:
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn or pip3 install --upgrade scikit-learn
As an alternative, if you cannot update scikit-learn, you can use the roc_curve function along with matplotlib to plot the ROC curve manually. Example Given here:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, roc_curve, roc_auc_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

# Sample data
X, y = np.random.rand(100, 10), np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Train a classifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_proba = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

# Calculate ROC curve
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_proba)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_proba)

# Plot ROC curve
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=2, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=2, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()





Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more
